# How to perform all delay operations right away with NSOperation or GCD?

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsoperationqueue, nsoperation

I have some operations with different delay times.

While using GCD it looks like:

```objectivec
dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayTime * NSEC_PER_MSEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        
   // do stuff
                        
});
```

Butt at some time I wanna perform all operations right away.

Is it possible with NSOperation or GCD?

Thanks

Comment: Why not just `do stuff`? Maybe you can explain the scenario in more details.

Comment: @BenjaminWen The scenario is that there is some time between  **video** and **chat message**, I wanna show the **chat message** according to the **video  time** in **SEI**. If I FF  the video, I need to show some chat messages immediately.

Comment: So the 'time between video and chat message' is not predetermined, then `dispatch_after` doesn't seem like a good choice.

Comment: @BenjaminWen Yeah, the time is dynamic and I save it as a property. When receiving a chat message I just dispatch_after it. Now the question is that I wanna perform the dispatch_after immediately.

Comment: `NSOperation` can certainly accommodate this by (a) observing the time and then (b) triggering `isReady` KVO when a certain amount of time has passed. But I contend that this idea of using an operation/dispatch queue to synchronize chat and video is deeply flawed, as the chat messages really aren't a queue. One really expects a bidirectionally to this synchronization (e.g., scrub backwards, one would reasonably expect the chat timeline to reflect that). Even if you aren't going to enable rewinding and scrubbing backwards at this point, it illustrates that a queue is just the wrong pattern.